# Entity Framework : ExecuteStoreQuery not found in ObjectContext

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express with Framework 4.0 and if I am correct, it comes with Entity Framework 4.

My ObjectContext is defined as:

```
public partial class CreaturesEntities : global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
```

I tried to use ExecuteStoreQuery :

```
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity;
[...]
context = new CreaturesEntities();
string query = "select type, min(value) value from saving_throw where ";
string conditions = "(classe_id=" + classe_id + " and level=" + level1 + ")";
if (classe.subclass1_id != null)
    conditions += " or (classe_id=" + classe.subclass1_id + " and level=" + level1 + ")";
if (classe.subclass2_id != null)
    conditions += " or (classe_id=" + classe.subclass2_id + " and level=" + level2 + ")";
if (classe.subclass3_id != null)
    conditions += " or (classe_id=" + classe.subclass3_id + " and level=" + level3 + ")";
query = query + conditions + " group by type";
var q = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<SimpleNumber>(query);
// SimpleNumber is a class with an int property, I suppose ExecuteStoreQuery<Integer> wouldn't work?
```

When I type "context.", I can't find ExecuteStoreQuery in context menu, which means it is not available for whatever reasons.
I can't find anything about a missing method in ObjectContext.
Does this mean that Visual Studio 2010 Express doesn't include Entity Framework 4 ? Because standard edition does, and it would be strange that express edition uses an older version.

Of course, I could use a classic DataReader but ExecuteStoreQuery is a lot better.

Any idea?

Edit : I change query to the real one to explain why ExecuteStoreQuery is sometimes easier for complex query (at least for beginners in LINQ To Entities)

Comment: I know that is called `ExecuteQuery` in Linq2SQL. You sure you have the correct name?

Comment: ExecuteStoreQuery is available in my Entity Framework project. I've just checked. But I've never used it. I do all my querying with linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx) instead?

```
context.Spells.Where(s => s.ID.Equals(1));
```

Comment: I edited my original query for the real one. It's complicated enough to justify the use of ExecuteStoreQuery. And even if I could do it in LINQ to Entities, I just wonder why ExecuteStoreQuery is not present on my ObjectContext

Comment: OK, but I would still use LINQ to Entities and write my own custom LINQ extension methods.

Comment: I've used LINQ to Entities finally, better than coding an extension method that should already exists. As I must hurry in my dev, I mark this question as answered, even it doesn't really the one I expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, where `ExecuteStoreQuery` was not present.  I discovered that my projects were defaulting to *.NET Framework **3.5***, and `ExecuteStoreQuery` appears when using *.NET Framework **4***.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when upgrading a legacy project to VS2013/MVC4/EF6.1

The best solution I found is [this EF 6.x EntityObject Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66612113-549c-4a9e-a14a-f629ceb3f89a).

There's also this hacky approach I initially took:

I changed the Code Generation Strategy in the edmx properties to `Legacy ObjectContext` and deleted the T4 template files.

This generated the model code as I expected it, but it wouldn't compile because of namespace changes in EF6. 
So I went into the generated code file and replaced every instance of `System.Data.X` that wasn't being resolved with `System.Data.Entity.Core.X`.

This is, of course, inadvisable, but will get your legacy project compiling and working as you expect it to.